# Number of zeros at the end of $10^{2}!+ 11^{2}!+12^{2}! \cdots+99^{2}!$

Tags: factorial

How do I find  the number of zeros at the end of the Integer $$10^{2}!+ 11^{2}!+12^{2}! \cdots+99^{2}!$$

Answer provided for this question is $24$

Comment: Can you answer a simpler question: how many zeros are at the end of the integer $100!$?

Comment: HINT: This number is divisible by $10^2!$ but not by $10\cdot10^2!$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number  of zeroes at  the end of all numbers $10^{2}!,\ \  11^{2}!,\ \ 12^{2}!,\ \  \cdots,\ \ 99^{2}!$, are equal or more than the one for $10^{2}!$.

So, you just need to count the number of zeroes at the end of $10^{2}!$

Moreover, we know that the number of zeroes at the end of $100!$ is equal to $\color{red}{\lfloor {\frac{100}{5}} \rfloor+\lfloor {\frac{100}{25}} \rfloor =24}$.

**Revise:** As Hagen mentioned here, the number of zeroes at the end of all the numbers $11^{2}!,\ \ 12^{2}!,\ \  \cdots,$ and $99^{2}!$ are more than $24$, that is the one for $10^2!$, and so the number of zeroes at the end of summation is equal to the number of zeroes at the end of $10^2!$.

Comment: @Ayushakj: This answer, unlike **Hagen von Eitzen**’s, is incomplete. If some of the terms $n^2!$ with $n>100$ also ended in $24$ zeroes, it would in principle be possible for the sum to end in more than $24$ zeroes: the non-zero digits in the $25$-th place from the right could sum to a multiple of $10$. Hagen shows that this does not happen.

Comment: I highly appreciate your attention to my answer. Some revisions have now been made to complete the solution.

Comment: Looks fine now; +1.

Comment: Are we so sure that the sum of the next digit over for $11^2!$ and $12^2!$ etc. are not $0$?

Comment: @Axoren when there are at least 25 zeroes at the end of the others, it does not matter what happens during the summation, because they finally sum up with $10^2!$ which has only $24$ zeroes at the end, and so the number of zeroes at the end of the total summation is $24$.

Comment: @Majid So $11^2!$ has more zeros than $10^2!$ guaranteed? If it had the same number of zeros, the sum of the next digits over could result in another $0$. But if it had strictly more zeros, the next digit over for $10^2!$ would be simply summed with $0$'s from that point further.

Comment: @Axoren $121!$ has $28$ zeroes at the end which is strictly more than $24$ as the number of zeroes at the end of $100!$.

Answer (score 3):

The number of zeroes at the end of $n!$ is $\lfloor \frac n5\rfloor+\lfloor \frac n{25}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac n{125}\rfloor+\ldots$.
In particular, $10^2!$ ends in $\lfloor\frac{100}5\rfloor +\lfloor\frac{100}{25}\rfloor+0=24$ zeroes.
On the other hand, for $n\ge 105$ (e.g., for $n=11^2,\ldots, 99^2$), the number $n!$ ends in at least $\lfloor\frac{105}5\rfloor +\lfloor\frac{105}{25}\rfloor=25$ zeroes. Adding such a number to $10^2!$ does not change any of the lower 25 digits and hence does not change the numbre of zeroes at the end.

Comment: How to you know the number of zeroes at the end of $n!$ is $\lfloor \frac n5\rfloor+\lfloor \frac n{25}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac n{125}\rfloor+\ldots$?